# Bash - Delete files in large directories

Tags: bash, performance, loops, delete-file

I have to delete files in very large directories (500k files) looks like:

```
Fiche_8317.doc
Fiche_8318.doc
Fiche_8319.doc
```

I code a loop to read a file `*deletedFiles.txt` which give me names I have to delete:

```
AAA;ZQ;00008319;2011-05-18;ACTA;RR02000354090127104747.doc
AAA;ZQ;00008320;2011-05-18;ACTA;RR02000354090127104747.doc
AAA;ZQ;00008321;2011-05-18;REDA;RR02000354090127104747.doc
AAA;ZQ;00008322;2011-05-18;ITAC;RR02000354090127104747.doc
```

I tried a loop like that *(not my real code, I change variable)*:

```
while IFS=";" read -r idt surname
do  
    Echo $idt " " $surname
    #Supress leading 0 and delete
    find $DataPath/target/ -type f -name Fiche_"$((10#$idt))".* -delete
    
done < <(cut -d ";" -f 3,6 $DataPath/*deletedFiles.txt)
```

This code works, but is extremely slow, more than 2 minutes per file on my Linux server.

There is only 1 file for each `idt` in the directory.

Could I improve that?
I'm looking for a faster solution.

Unfortunately I have to use bash only cause the scheduler in my company only works with bash.

Thank you a lot

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what your code is doing, or rather what *needs* to be done, instead of posting code that contains *at least* two typos (i.e. is NOT the actual code you are running)...

Comment: Is the directory structure flat, i.e. are all files in `.../target/`, or are we looking at subdirectories? Is there a way to limit the subdirectories your `find` is looking in? Can you edit the input files, so the "supress leading 0" is already done? Do you really need to `find` the files, or can we come up with something like `rm $DataPath/target/Fiche_${idt}.*`? Right now, you are not giving enough information to give a good answer.

Comment: Please show 4-5 typical lines from your *"deletedText"* file and the full paths of corresponding files that get deleted as a result.

Comment: The repeated runs of `find` is almost certainly a big reason it's slow. What `find` does is scan an entire directory tree examining each file to see if it matches the criteria; in this case, for each file it finds and deletes, it *also* has to examine every other file, decide its name doesn't match, and ignore it ("is this it?" "no" "is this it?" "no" ...). You want something that either goes directly to the right file without having to look at all the others, or just runs `find` once and lets it find *all* of the files to be deleted in a single pass.

Comment: Complementing the correct answer by _Fravadona_: Since speed is an issue, a good algorithm would use a collection (`Set` or `Array`) of filenames, traverse the file tree once and for each file in the tree check whether the filename is contained in the collection. This means that we would implement this ideally not in bash, but in a language, which not only has an equivalent to the `find` command, but also can easily model such collections (`Ruby`, `Python`, `Perl`, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I add an exemple of my deletedText on the topic
There is only 1 file like "Fiche_${idt}" in my repository, maybe rm $DataPath/target/Fiche_${idt}.* could be usefull.
Unfortunately I have to use bash only cause the scheduler in my company only works with bash.

Comment: If your file is called `Fiche_8319.doc` it must be in the current directory, so there is no need to use `find`, surely? How many files are there in the directory you are looking in (roughly), and how many are there in `deletedFiles.txt` roughly and how many will get deleted roughly? The fact that your scheduler starts in `bash` does not prevent you from calling `Perl` or `Python` any more than it prevents you calling `find` and `cut` as you currently do.

Answer (score 1):

What takes a lot of time is to walk though the directories in search of the files to delete. For speeding it up you can call `find` a single time, filter the filepaths with GNU `awk` and call `rm` with `xargs -0`

```bash
find "$DataPath"/target -type f -print0 |
awk -v ORS='\0' '
    FNR == NR { prefixes[sprintf("Fiche_%d", $3)]; next }
    match($NF, /^[^.]+/) && (substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH) in prefixes)
' FS=';' "$DataPath"/deletedFiles.txt RS='\0' FS='/' - |
xargs -0 rm --
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hoping* that the asterisk in the file name `*deletedFiles` was a typo:

```
cut -d';' -f3 "$DataPath/deletedFiles.txt" | \
    sed "s/^0*\(.*\)/rm \"$DataPath/target/Fiche_\1.doc\"/" | \
    source /dev/stdin
```

- `cut -d';' -f3` gets the third field from the input. I dropped the `echo` line from your example as you're looking for performance.
- `sed s/^0*\(.*\)/...` strips leading zeroes from that field...
- `.../rm $DataPath/target/Fiche_\1.doc/` ...prepends the `rm` command, the path, and appends `.doc`.
- `source /dev/stdin` runs the result from the pipe (sequence of `rm` commands) in the current shell. (This feature was bugged prior to bash v4.0.)

You can probably squeeze some more performance out of this if you get multiple files onto one command line to be deleted by a single `rm`, but I am not sure if it would be worth the additional complexity, both performance and maintenance wise.